# How do I search for a field in an ado database in delphi with a sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, delphi, delphi-7

I have tried to filter through an ado database table on delphi.

I have a dbgrid connected to the query(qryData), as soon as this code executes then the dbgrid goes blank and nothing further happens. Even if I type in a valid field name, it should then display it in the dbgrid but it shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure TfrmProjects.cbxColumnsSelect(Sender: TObject);
begin
if edtsearch.Text = '' then
    begin
      showmessage('The search field should be entered');
      exit;
    end
else
    begin
        ssearch:= edtsearch.Text;
        showmessage(ssearch);
    end;

 if cbxColumns.ItemIndex = -1 then
  begin
    showmessage('Please select a field');
    exit;
  end
 else
  begin
    scolumn:= cbxColumns.Items[cbxColumns.itemindex];
    showmessage(scolumn);
  end;

with dmUsers do
begin
  with qryData do
    begin
      sql.Clear;
      sql.Text := 'Select * FROM tbl_projects where' + quotedstr(scolumn) + ' = ' +quotedstr(ssearch);
      open;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: sorry my code block is not very neat

Comment: "Filter" is probably not the right word for what you want to do.  Just to be clear:  Is what you are trying to do is to have the user select from a combobox the column in the associated table that the user wishes to search upon, prompt the user fir a value in the table column to match and then execute a Sql query to find table rows matching the query?

Comment: @user2595912 : `... where' + quotedstr(scolumn)` will become `... where"xyfield"` as you can see there is no space between `where` and `"xyfield"` !

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me.  You will need to change the references to qryData to dmUsers.qryData.  Btw, try and avoid using "with ..."

Note that the SQL you are constructing isn't ideal, because it doesn't take account of whether the column being searched upon is of a datatype which requires the value specified in the query to be surrounded in quotes.  The column name doesn't need to be in quotes, but may need square brackets [ ] around it if it has embedded spaces.  The fact that you included quotes around the column name was the reason the grid went blank - what you were asking the Sql search engine on the server for is all rows where 'one string' = 'another string', which is false for any row so none is returned.  Btw, this is related to Sql examples you sometimes see which have a where clause like 'where 1 = 2'; that's never true, of course, and the idea is to force the search engine to parse the query without returning any rows.

As @mostkito-x commented, one of the main problems with the original version of your query was lack of space between the elements of the query   Use spaces liberally so you can see what you're doing. When you're having trouble with a query no bad thing to put its text into a memo (set to a fixed-pitched font like Courier) on your form, so you can eyeball whether you're actually constructing the query you think you are.

Btw, in case you hadn't gathered, using QuotedStr around the search value for string datatypes has the advantage of correctly handling the case where the search value has an embedded quote (like o'Reilly).

```
procedure TForm1.CbxColumnNameClick(Sender: TObject);
//  NOTE: The following code assumes that either qryData is open when it is called
//        or has persistent TFields defined
var
  FieldName,
  ValueToSearch,
  Sql : String;
  UseQuotedValue : Boolean;
begin
  FieldName := cbxColumnName.Text;
  if FieldName = '' then begin
    ShowMessage('No field selected for search.');
    Exit;
  end;

  UseQuotedValue := qryData.FieldByName(FieldName).DataType in [ftString, ftWideString, ftMemo];

  ValueToSearch := edtSearch.Text;
  if  UseQuotedValue then
    ValueToSearch := QuotedStr(ValueToSearch);

  Sql := 'select * from tblProjects where ' + FieldName + ' = ' + ValueToSearch;

  if qryData.Active then
    qryData.Close;
  qryData.SQL.Text := Sql;
  qryData.Open;
end;
```

Also with queries of this type read up on "SQL Injection" malware risks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).  The received wisdom is that a measure to reduce the risk of this is to use parameterized queries.  Unfortunately for your task, although you can specify the column value to be matched as a parameter, you can't parameterize the column *name* in ADO.

To use a parameterized query, the Sql would look something like

Select * from tblProjects where SomeColumn = :somevalue

Then, in the IDE Object Inspector you'd need to define a parameter on qryData and, before executing the query, do qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('somevalue').Value := edtSearch.Text.  But, like I said, you can't parameterize the column name to search on.

Comment: +1 good that you mention : `try and avoid using "with ..."`. You should also mention that a query is often due to lack of space between the instructions fails. if you look at the finished `sqlquery`, mostly falls on what is wrong.

Comment: @moskitox, yes good point, I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: please adapt your example and show usage of parameters, or else no +1 ;)

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Actually, the bit about parameters was intended as a bit of an aside, and not really what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Agreed, but there is only one secure way. I applaud you for mentioning SQL injection, but for future reference it would be better to incorporate parameter usage in the sample so other users can learn how to do it the right way... :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Ithought I had -see "To use a parameterized query, the Sql would look something like [et seq]" in my answer.  Or are you saying I should say smth more or different?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Well, no, I don't see how.  The OP was asking about how to construct a query where the column to be searched on, and so far as I know a Sql query (against Sql sever at any rate) can't handle the column name as a parameter.  But maybe we are talking at cross purposes or I am being obtuse (frequently happens).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the problem is in this line:

```
sql.Text := 'Select * FROM tbl_projects where' + quotedstr(scolumn) + ' = ' +quotedstr(ssearch);
```

It should be:

```
sql.Text := 'Select * FROM tbl_projects where ' + scolumn + ' = ' +quotedstr(ssearch);
```

The first QuotedStr quotes the column name with regular single quotes, which will compate two string values - one equal to the name of the column, and the other rqual to the search string.

If you are using spaces in column names, you should enclose it with appropriate characters. For example, in MySql you should use:

```
sql.Text := 'Select * FROM tbl_projects where `' + scolumn + '` = ' +quotedstr(ssearch);
```